Sending Data To PartialView Which is Called From View
In View I am calling a Partial View like this.
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x=>x.VariantName))
{
   <partial name="VariantsListItem" model="item" />
}

The Problem is besides model I want to send some data to this partial view. Is it possible to send a viewbag or something like it when I call partial view like this.

Yes, you can use view-data attribute that assigns a ViewDataDictionary to pass to the partial view. You can do this in your case:
@{
    ViewData["MyData"] = 1;
}

@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x=>x.VariantName))
{
   <partial name="VariantsListItem" model="item" view-data="ViewData" />
}

In the above code, the MyData key value is set to 1 and added to the ViewData collection so you can retrieve the ViewData in your partial view like:
@{
    int myData= (int)ViewData["MyData"];
}


OK but what If I want to send 2 view data. I think it only allows me to send one viewdata
